# How to find country from ip adress?

Tags: c#

I am using [this API](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php) to find the country of a user. I am able to find the country on a web page in XML format. [Here](http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-country/?key=5d3d0cdbc95df34b9db4a7b4fb754e738bce4ac914ca8909ace8d3ece39cee3b&ip=74.125.45.100) you can see XML file example. But the problem is i can not read this XML in my c# code. Here is my code

```
string UserIP = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString();
string ApiKey = "5d3d0cdbc95df34b9db4a7b4fb754e738bce4ac914ca8909ace8d3ece39cee3b";
string Url = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-country/?key=" + ApiKey + "&ip=" + UserIP;
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(Url);
```

But this code returns following exception on loading the xml.

> *System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.*

Please describe the exact method to read this XML.

Comment: I don't think sharing your API-key is allowed by your API provider.

Comment: What you've linked to doesn't look like XML to me.

Comment: @Levente i got this API-key after registration on the site.

Comment: an API Key is like a password for your application, I believe he is suggesting you not list your personal API Key on a public forum for your (and your API Provider's) security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll say that it isn't an XML but simply a string subdivided by `;`:

By giving an impossible IP address we can see that it's so composed:

```
OK;;74.125.45.100;US;UNITED STATES
ERROR;Invalid IP address.;127.0.0.1.1;;

OK/ERROR
If ERROR, complete ERROR message
IP Address
Abbreviation of country
Country name
```

This code should do:

```
string userIP = "127.0.0.1";
string apiKey = "5d3d0cdbc95df34b9db4a7b4fb754e738bce4ac914ca8909ace8d3ece39cee3b";
string url = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-country/?key=" + apiKey + "&ip=" + userIP;

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    // We try to use the "correct" charset
    Encoding encoding = response.CharacterSet != null ? Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet) : null;

    using (var sr = encoding != null ? new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding) :
                                       new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), true))
    {
        var response2 = sr.ReadToEnd();
        var parts = response2.Split(';');

        if (parts.Length != 5)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        string okError = parts[0];
        string message = parts[1];
        string ip = parts[2];
        string code = parts[3];
        string country = parts[4];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I'd do:

- Using a HTTP transfer, query the site, and buffer the results
- Convert it into a String
- Use a splitting algorithm on it to make into an array.
- Check if the 0th element of the array equals 'OK'
- If not, bail out.
- If so, check the third and fourth elements for country code, and country name respectively.

Answer (score 1):

from the [IP Location XML API Documentation](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php): API Parameter format, required = false, default = raw, values = raw, xml, json.  so I have tested it and `string Url = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-country/?key=" + ApiKey + "&ip=" + UserIP + "&format=xml"` gives a parsable xml result.